# NSIS: How to distinguish between Cancel and Close button

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

In NSIS, on a custom page, I want to skip the page when the user presses the Cancel button, but I want to exit the installer (with confirmation) when the user presses the window's X button. How do I do that?

Currently, by using Modern UI and custom abort function, I get the same function called regardless of which of the two buttons is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal installer behavior and I would not recommend that you try to implement this.

If you still want to try I guess it might be possible with the [ButtonEvent plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ButtonEvent_plug-in) or the [WndSubclass plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WndSubclass_plug-in)...

Comment: Thank you. The ButtonEvent plug-in helped, but I needed to use the Back button instead of the Cancel button. For what it's worth, assigning a button event to the Cancel button will fire that event when clicking the X close button as well.